# Using an object in a single return line without declaration

Tags: c#, simplify

Here is a piece of code

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var myObj= obj as MyClass;
            return obj == null || myObj== null || !ReferenceEquals(this, obj) ? false :
                (this.V1== myObj.V1) && (this.V2== myObj.V2) && (this.V3== myObj.V3);
        }
```

Is it possible to use myObj in the return line without declaring it above?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, `return obj == null || obj as MyClass == null || !ReferenceEquals(this, obj) ? false : true;`.

Comment: You could even do this: `return obj as MyClass != null && ReferenceEquals(this, obj);`.

Comment: Oh yeah.. I'm a bit stupid, I've hidden the part of the code that actually caused problem, let me edit...

Comment: Yes indeed! :) It is getting a lot better! Thank you for that tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the answer is "yes", but that's not actually a good sign. After doing a cast, if you are going to use the result of the cast several times, it's a completely expected thing that you need to put it into some kind of a temporary variable.

In the code you presented, the whole expression before `?` can be simplified to just `ReferenceEquals(this, obj)` since reference-equals should already be safe with nulls.

Also, since you're doing reference-equals, and return `false` when it fails, then you don't need any other checks. The right-side of `:` is superfluous. It activates only when ref-equals returns true, but then such case means that the two variables under comparison are actually the very same object - so all other comparisons would return true anyways - so no need for them.

so.. the whole code reduces to

```
return ReferenceEquals(this, obj);
```

..at least that's how your current expression works.

Due to that "it-all-reduces-to-just-referenceequality" I actually think you didn't want it that way.

I think you wanted to check if they are ref-equal and then return true quickly. Then only if they were not ref-equal, you'd perform piece-wise comparisons of inner properties. Something like:

```
if(refequals(a,b)) return true;
if((a==null) != (b==null)) return false;
return a.prop1==b.prop1 && a.prop2 == b.prop2 && ... ;
```

.. and then you can compact it to a one-liner, but what's the point? Compacting it just makes it harder to read, there's no real performance gain, it just packs it all into a one line which is even not a gain in terms of "length of text" since you can simply "fold" the function in most IDEs...

(BTW. in code final line is a/b/null-safe thanks to refequals taht will catch case of 2 nulls and the tricky second line that catches all cases of 1-sided null)